# launchSettings.json automatically generated by Visual Studio

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

I don't remember ever seeing launchSettings.json when I was using Visual Studio. And I didn't realize the role of launchSettings.json at work. It seems that launchSettings.json is not used in my VS project, but after deleting it, VS will automatically generate launchSettings.json as soon as the solution is opened. How to solve it?

How to solve it? I need some understandable explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The launchSettings.json file in Visual Studio stores configuration information for debugging applications. It allows you to specify various settings for running applications.
The launchSettings.json file is typically located in the Properties folder of a .NET Core or ASP.NET Core project. Visual Studio uses it to configure the project's debugging environment.

Of course, even if you delete launchSettings.json, the above information will be regenerated, which may affect the running speed of the project.

Also, you just need to add the following code to your csproj file to stop generating launchSettings.json:

```
<NoDefaultLaunchSettingsFile>true</NoDefaultLaunchSettingsFile>
```